# Explain np.polyfit and np.polyval for a scatter plot

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have to make a scatter plot and liner fit to my data. prediction_08.Dem_Adv and prediction_08.Dem_Win are two column of datas. I know that np.polyfit returns coefficients. But what is np.polyval doing here? I saw the documentation, but the explanation is confusing. can some one explain to me clearly

```
plt.plot(prediction_08.Dem_Adv, prediction_08.Dem_Win, 'o')
plt.xlabel("2008 Gallup Democrat Advantage")
plt.ylabel("2008 Election Democrat Win")
fit = np.polyfit(prediction_08.Dem_Adv, prediction_08.Dem_Win, 1)
x = np.linspace(-40, 80, 10)
y = np.polyval(fit, x)
plt.plot(x, y)
print fit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.polyval` is applying the polynomial function which you got using `polyfit`. If you get y = mx+ c relationship. The `np.polyval` function will multiply your x values with `fit[0]` and add `fit[1]`
Polyval according to Docs:

```
N = len(p)
y = p[0]*x**(N-1) + p[1]*x**(N-2) + ... + p[N-2]*x + p[N-1]
```

If the relationship is `y = ax**2 + bx + c`,

```
fit = np.polyfit(x,y,2)
a = fit[0]
b = fit[1]
c = fit[2]
```

If you do not want to use the polyval function:

```
y = a*(x**2) + b*(x) + c
```

This will create the same output as polyval.